# GROUP BY with condition

Tags: sql-server

I've got a table like this

```
accountid (int)
emailaddress (varchar)
email(bit)
postal(bit)
sms(bit)
telephone(bit
```

accountid is unique, but emailaddress could have duplicates,

```
accountid emailaddress    email postal sms  telephone
62626     test@test.com   0     1      0    1
76364     blah@blah.com   0     0      0    1
37374     test@test.com   NULL  NULL   NULL NULL
```

I want to create a query that groups by the emailaddress, but which chooses the record where email is not null, if there is no not null record then any can be chosen.

In this example I want to end up with

```
accountid emailaddress    email postal sms  telephone
62626     test@test.com   0     1      0    1
76364     blah@blah.com   0     0      0    1
```

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Tried a standard GROUP BY emailaddress, but no idea how to add the condition.

Comment: If you add DDL to your question it really helps people to help you.  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

ok. What i understand is that you want the records where email address is not null and any field value from these fields(email, postal, sms, telephone) should not be null. Then try this:

```
Select * 
from yourtable 
where emailaddress is not null 
  and (email is not null 
       AND postal is not null 
       AND sms is not null 
       AND telephone is not null)
Group By emailaddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (accountid INT, emailaddress VARCHAR(50), email INT,  postal INT, sms  INT, telephone INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES(62626,'test@test.com' ,  0   ,  1    ,  0 ,   1)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES(76364,'blah@blah.com' ,  0   ,  0    ,  0 ,   1)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES(37374,'test@test.com' ,  NULL   ,  NULL    ,  NULL ,  NULL)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES(11111,'null@null.com' ,  NULL   ,  NULL    ,  NULL ,  NULL)

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN email IS NOT NULL THEN accountid ELSE accountid END) 
    ,emailaddress
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN email IS NOT NULL THEN email ELSE email END) 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN email IS NOT NULL THEN postal ELSE postal END) 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN email IS NOT NULL THEN sms ELSE sms END) 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN email IS NOT NULL THEN telephone ELSE telephone END) 
FROM @Tab
GROUP BY emailaddress
```

**OutPut:**

```
76364   blah@blah.com   0       0       0       1
11111   null@null.com   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
62626   test@test.com   0       0       0       1
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN email IS NOT NULL THEN email ELSE email END` ?